# Exhibit timeline ex:start acceptable date format

Tags: simile

I'm not sure what is the date format i should use in order for timeline to work properly. Here is the code and a brief explanation of things i tried after it:

```
<div ex:role="view"
                   ex:viewClass="Timeline"
                   ex:start=".Ddate"
                   ex:colorKey=".feedTitle">
</div>
```

Now i have tried putting (dd-MM-yyyy) and raw date format generated from .toString(). But none of it worked. In some tutorials i have tried for exhibit they only worked with years, but for rss reader that is pretty much pointless because rss is updated on daily bases.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format is as follows:
yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm

http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Exhibit/How_to_make_an_exhibit_from_data_fed_directly_from_a_Google_Spreadsheet